# How much does the U.S. give Africa for the development of infrastructure?

Tags: united-states, africa, infrastructure, foreign-aid

https://sgp.fas.org/crs/row/R46368.pdf

Looking at this I found that infrastructure is categorized as "Other Economic Growth Efforts", and it seems that infrastructure is not included in the figures. I only see a broad category called "Trade and investment assistance", but it seems to cover other spending. It's set at 134 million, but I would like to know if there's a more reliable figure than that.

> Economic Growth (including Climate Change). Economic growth assistance
> would see a 50% upswing from FY2021 allocations, with $936 million
> requested for FY2023.51 Aid for agriculture, the largest focus area of
> U.S. economic growth funding for Africa, would see a $65 million
> increase from FY2021 (see Text Box). Trade and investment assistance
> would also increase, to $134 million, including $100 million for
> Prosper Africa and $27 million requested separately for USAID’s East
> Africa, Southern Africa, and West Africa regional operating units. The
> request proposes $20 million for USAID’s Africa Regional Bureau (AFR)
> for “Digital Africa,” intended to “foster the growth of an inclusive
> and resilient African digital ecosystem led by African communities and
> built on an open, interoperable, reliable, and secure Internet.”